# Can an Activity be notified when a fragment is killed?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

Is there any function that is called when a fragment is killed? Or can an Activity listen for such changes like fragment removal etc?

Comment: `onDetach()` called immediately prior to the fragment no longer being associated with its activity.

Comment: @MD : But that is a method in Fragment. I want to listen for changes in the activtiy

Comment: You are trying to inform the parent(Activity) of a child's(Fragment) lifecycle. the `onFragmentInteractionListener` could be useful and/or the lifecycle methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here are some of fragment life cycle methods names are pretty self describing 
you can call your activity's method from those bellow

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
}
```

ok here is a way to add listener to your activity.

1 create Callback interface like this

```
public interface CallBack<T> {
    void onCall(int key, T body);
}
```

2 make your activity to implement it  e.g.

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity implements Callback
```

once you do that you will need to implement onCall method in your activity class
`onCall` is a method that will be called from fragment

3 in your fragment class ad a member variable

```
private Callback<TypeYouWant>  callback;
```

4 create a setter for callback

```
public void setCallBack(Callback c){
     this.callback = c;
}
```

5 go to you activity and setCallback, since your activity knows about your fragment therefore you have reference to it. at least you can get it with `getFragmentManager().findFragmentById()` . in activity's onCreate method add this

```
 myFragment.setCallback(this) //note you can pass **this** because your activity implements `Callback` interface
```

6 last step , in your fragment's onDetach add

@Override

```
public void onDetach() {
   super.onDetach();
   if(callback !=null){
      callback.call(some key, some T type value);
    }
}
```

so that's it whenever onDetach called in fragment your activity will get callback

Comment: I want to listen for the fragment detach in the activity.

Comment: ok suppose your activity has a method doMagic()
inside onDetach() you can write
((MyActivity)getActivity()).doMagic();

or if it can be any general activity and you want ot avoid cast there is another better way, if you want I can add it to answer

Comment: @ Vilen Melkumyan : You can add it if you feel that it's a better way. Suggestions are always welcome

Comment: added edit which step by step describes how to add listener to your activity